# Angular 14 mat-checkbox not clickable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I got an app that uses a schema to define the columns of an editable mat-table.

The problem is that when I click the pencil, the checkboxes aren't clickable.  For more details, I suggest you go see the stackblitz project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tjsqam?file=src/app/app.component.html

Code example :

```
<div *ngIf="col.key != 'isEdit'">
  <input
    [type]="col.type"
    [(ngModel)]="element[col.key]"
    [checked]="GetCheckBoxValue(element, col.key)"
  />
```

In not editing mode :

[image]

In editing mode :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is in Angular 15

change the following thing, this should make the checkbox work

```html
<tr
  mat-row
  *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
  (click)="clickedRows.add(row)"
  [class.highlightTableColor]="clickedRows.has(row)"
></tr>
```

```js
clickedRows = new Set<model>();
```

or remove the return statement from the highlight method

```js
highlight(row: { ID: number }) {
  if (!this.editing) this.selectedID = row.ID;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it.  I was looking at the wrong place obviously.  It was the return false of the highlight.